# How to print $node inside hook_exit

Tags: drupal-7, hook

I have a requirement were I wanted to insert few values depending on whether the node is of type 'news', but when I try to do that with the following code, its seems not working, Could someone help with the code,

```
function hook_exit() {
  if (isset($node) && $node->type == 'event') {
    print_r('This is an event');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Drupal 7 API Reference for hook_exit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_exit/7):

> This hook MUST NOT print anything because by the time it runs the response is already sent to the browser.

If you'd like to add information to nodes as they're loaded from the database by Drupal, try using [hook_node_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7). For example:

```
function yourmodule_node_load($nodes, $types) 
{
  foreach ($nodes as $node) 
  {
    // To add or override a node attribute
    $node->myvar = "Value"; 

    // To print some data from the node
    print_r($node->title);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To meet my requirement for getting the type, what I did is I have checked the url, took the second argument and passed it as the parameter for node_load function. It is a bit tricky, but it did the job for me.

```
function tru_statistics_exit() {
  if ((arg(0) == 'node') && is_numeric(arg(1)) && arg(2) == '') {
    $nid = arg(1);
    $node = node_load($nid); 
    if ($node->type == 'event') {
      get_details_visitor();
    }
  }
}
```

Hope some one will find this helpfull